# Computing: 32 bit or 32 bits?

Tags: grammatical-number, computing

This question comes from this [other](https://superuser.com/questions/845537/bit-bits-specification-what-is-the-corrrect-way-to-spell-64-bit-or-64-bits-n) debate at SuperUser Forum.
I have asked it here too because:

- It appears not to be only a **technical** question, but a language question too.
- Most of the answers in the referred thread until now seem to me most like "Everybody says 32 bit, so it must be correct" kind, instead of **reason and logic** based.

The question is: as long as a computer that works with, say, 64 bit(s) uses **more bit(s)** for computing than a computer that works with, say, 32 bit(s), **should we say** ... ?

- 32 bit operating system
- 32 bits operating system

What if we change "operating system" by "graphics card", "motherboard", or "version of the program"?

Comment: This question is actually not clear at all. (And the linked original even less so.) What do you mean "should we say"? What is the exact context? What is the sentence you want to use it in? The answer depends on what part of speech we are talking about. As a modifier, it is "32-bit". Never "32-bits". As a noun, it is exactly the other way round. The reason and logic behind this being that this is exactly how all other nouns and modifiers behave in English.

Comment: Sorry, @RegDwigнt. I have added some context examples to my original post. For what you say, I think those case examples are modifiers, so it seems to me "32-bit" is correct.

Comment: 32 bit should be an adjective abd 32 bits a noun phrase